# Understanding the paper "Why war is a man's game"

Tags: evolution, theoretical-biology, evolutionary-game-theory

I have read this article

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2018.0975

but I don't understand the mathematics which tries to explain why war is male-exclusive. In which branch of mathematics the mathematical theory outlined here can be seen? Is it Game theory? Which mechanisms this mathematical model predicts?
Is this really a new theory?

Comment: One has to follow the references, since the method is not explained: judging by the figures it is non-linear equations analysis, such as appears in common population, competition or epidemiologic models. These are obviously motivated by some game-theoretical analysis and basic population biology/genetics considerations.

Comment: I am sorry but questions here have to be comprehensible in themselves. Unless you can include the mathematics that you do not understand then it doesn’t fit the SE model.

Comment: Judging from the plots it seems like non-linear dynamics. Steven Strogatz's book on the subject is a good introduction.

Comment: you are probably better off changing the title to reflect the need for help with the math. you need very specific help. you should also edit your question to include the math itself, this will help as not everyone will be able to access the full article.

Comment: @John the article is open access, so everyone (with an internet connection) should be able to access it. Understanding the math is another issue entirely...

Comment: *evolutionary game theory* is probably the closest rubric.